# AppiumPython Profile Chrome

Tags: python, android, google-chrome, webdriver, appium

I am encountering a big problem with Appium; I want to control the Chrome browser on an Android tablet, but I would like to keep the data (cookies, etc.) between two tests. However, every time I restart my Appium test, the profile is reset to zero!!! Here is my configuration in Python :

```
desired_caps = {
        "newCommandTimeout": 0,
        "platformName": "Android",
        "platformVersion": versionAndroid,
        "deviceName": nomDevice,
        "browserName": "Chrome",
        "chromedriverExecutable": "/usr/local/bin/chromedriver",
        "automationName": "UiAutomator2",
        "noReset": True,
        "fullReset": False,
        "orientation": "LANDSCAPE",
        "chromeOptions": {
            "w3c": False,
            "androidKeepAppDataDir": True,
            'args': [
                        
                        'disable-features=TranslateUI',
                        'disable-features=Translate',
                    ],
        }
    }
```

Do you have any idea why this is not working even with the parameters :

```
"noReset": True,
"fullReset": False,
...
"androidKeepAppDataDir": True,
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Alexis

I don't know what parameters to use anymore to prevent the profile from being erased between two tests!!!